# Auto record delete after 10 minutes in Postgresql and using Springboot

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We using SpringBoot and SpringData with Postgresql, I want to auto-delete the newly inserted record in the table after 10 minutes.

Every new record will persist only in 10 minutes after 10 minutes it should be auto delete.

Any solution for Auto delete record?

**Note:** I don't want any Scheduler to do this job, please provide any other solution.

Thanks
Yasir

Comment: I don't know if you could do this without any scheduler. One possibility would be a trigger function that deletes older records on insert/update on the table but that way older records would still exists until an insert or update happens.

Comment: If you want data to disappear after 10 minutes, then I don't think you're looking for an RDBMS; you probably want something like [Redis](https://redis.io/), which has data expiry built in

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution is not to delete the entries, but add a creation timestamp and only select those rows that are no older than 10 minutes.

You can purge old records regularly, say every day, either by deleting them or (if you use partitioning) by dropping partitions.